# jQuery document load not being called

Tags: javascript, jquery

when I click the button nothing happens, I can't find my error:

```
<html>
<head>    
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js" />
</head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">    
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#btnSubmit").click(function(){
      alert("button");
  });
});

</script>
<input id = "btnSubmit" type="submit" value="Release"/>
</body>
</html>
```

can you give me a hing?

Comment: Your script tag isn't properly closed. Even the syntax highlighter above caught it.

Comment: Any errors in your [JavaScript console](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers)? For starters, your `<script>` tag is incomplete. You can't use  a single tag - you have to close it, i.e. `<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>`

Answer (score 1):

Try this code.

```
<html>
<head>    
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">    
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#btnSubmit").click(function(){
      alert("button");
  });
});

</script>
<input id = "btnSubmit" type="submit" value="Release"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have added jquery CDN so you can replace with your own local jquery file path.